# Find nested arrays based on inner array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, reduce

I'm currently working with an array of nested arrays and attempting to pull out certain arrays if they meet a condition (length greater than 1). Here's the array -

```
const testArr = [
  {
    "type": 1,
    "categories": [
      {
        "description": "Foo",
        "subOptions": [
          {
            "subType": 1,
            "subTypeTypeDescription": "Bar"
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": 2,
    "categories": [
      {
        "description": "Baz",
        "subOptions": [
          {
            "subType": 2,
            "subTypeTypeDescription": "Baf"
          },
          {
            "subType": 3,
            "subTypeTypeDescription": "Bee"
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I'm hoping to produce is an array of categories, but only if those categories have a subOptions array with a length > 1. Here is the hoped for result on the array above -

```
[
  {
    "description": "Baz",
    "subOptions": [
      {
        "subType": 2,
        "subTypeTypeDescription": "Baf"
      },
      {
        "subType": 3,
        "subTypeTypeDescription": "Bee"
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

I can get this to work by using normal foreach loops like so -

```
  let categories: [];

  testArr.forEach((service) => {
    service.categories.forEach((cat) => {
        if(cat.subOptions.length > 1) {
          categories.push(cat)
        }
    })
  })
```

but I'm trying to learn how to do these things with functional tools. I've tried to do it now several times with a mix of map, filter, and reduce and keep failing. If anyone can offer some direction on the most optimal way to do the same thing with functional methods, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `.filter` that checks the length of the sub-array:

```js
const testArr=[{type:1,categories:[{description:"Foo",subOptions:[{subType:1,subTypeTypeDescription:"Bar"}]}]},{type:2,categories:[{description:"Baz",subOptions:[{subType:2,subTypeTypeDescription:"Baf"},{subType:3,subTypeTypeDescription:"Bee"}]}]}];

const result = testArr
  .flatMap(item => item.categories)
  .filter(({ subOptions }) => subOptions.length >= 2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I'm going to have to play around with flatMap. I knew filter would be used but didn't know how to functionally get the array flattened to use filter.

Comment: For the *exact* structure in the input you could use `.map` alone: `.map(item => item.categories[0])`, but the general case could probably have more `categories` than just one, right?

Comment: Yeah exactly, there are times the length will be well over 1.

Comment: @ssdev You might also need to consider that flatMap is not supported in Internet Explorer but if your app doesn't include the IE in the equation, all is good with the solution above which is a very interesting one :)

Comment: Yeah, `flatMap` is a modern shortcut. An alternative is `[].concat.apply(...testArr.map(item => item.categories))` transpiled (if you're supporting IE, you better be transpiling)

Comment: ah ok, thanks. I will need this in IE11 but it should get transpiled down. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  const categories = testArr.map(service => {
    return service.categories.filter(category => category.subOptions.length > 1);
  })
```

Or even this in one line:

```
const categories = testArr.map(service => service.categories.filter(category => category.subOptions.length > 1));
```